# is a more specific HTTP code a "Semver breaking change"?

Tags: http, semantic-versioning

Lets say my version of my SemVer API is 2.0.0

Suppose I have an endpoint `/foo` that right now that erroneously always returns a `{200, "some message"}` or `{500, "some message"}`

I fix a bug so that I now detect bad requests, and now I return `{200, "some message"}` or `{400, "some message"}` or `{500, "some message"}`

Is this considered an API Breaking change in SemVer? The user may not be expecting the 400, so I can see the case for `3.0.0`, however I can also see that this should have been a 400 on a BAD REQUEST all along, because in some sense "HTTP" is my API, hence a patch fix to `2.0.1`, so I am torn.

Comment: In this hypo, would you have been returning useful messages along with your `500` responses, or just a generic message?

Comment: no my 500 was a generic message that was wrong in the case of bad requests

Answer (score 0):

I think that before answering this, you must determine philosophically where responsibility lies.  Namely, if client code is not capable of handling a new (correct) status code, is that break fairly the result of your change or the result of poorly written client code. If you had previously been sending some useful information along with your `500` responses, then it would be reasonable to expect that client code may have relied upon it.

To me, it sounds like the very definition of a [minor](http://semver.org/) change:

> MINOR version [is] when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner[. . .]

Actual internal server errors are still sent properly and successful results are still sent properly; what you've done is simply added the ability for clients to determine from where errors arise.

**edit**: So instead of `2.0.1` or `3.0.0`, I believe this would be `2.1.0`.